# JSF Portal Integration with ChemWriter and ChemVector

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I want to know whether someone have used `ChemWriter` and `Chemvector` chemical structure editing software?

I have question regarding this software.

I am working on a project involving **JSF portlet integration** with ChemWriter and ChemVector.

My question is how to bring the chemical **structure(molfile)** in Chemvector into ChemWriter in order to edit that particular Structure(molfile)?

Thanks in advance.